# Customize handlerOptions

Tags: openlayers-2, map-drawing

when I customize handlerOptions of drawfeature, savestrategy does not work. Here's my code :

```
var handoptions = {
        handlerOptions: {
            freehand: true,
            style: {
                fillColor: "yellow",
                fillOpacity: 0.4,
                strokeColor: "green",
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokeWidth: 1,
                pointRadius: 6
            }
        }
    };

    draw = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
       wfs_layer, OpenLayers.Handler.Point,handoptions,
       {
           //  title: "Draw Feature",
           //  displayClass: "olControlDrawFeaturePolygon",
           multi: true,
       }
       );
```

I don't know why ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the 'handlerOptions' as one option of OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature control.
Following code should work.

```
var myHandlerOptions = {
    // freehand: true,    // Point handler does not have freehand mode
    style: {
        fillColor: "yellow",
        fillOpacity: 0.4,
        strokeColor: "green",
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWidth: 1,
        pointRadius: 6
    }
};

var drawControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
    wfs_layer,
    OpenLayers.Handler.Point,
    {
        handlerOptions: myHandlerOptions,
        // title: "DrawFeature",
        // displayClass: "olControlDrawFeaturePolygon",
        multi: true
    }
);
```